# Android zoom and pan overlay UI according to ImageView(Touch) matrix

Tags: imageview, android

I'm trying to create an interface that has a map (image) with clickable elements like text or buttons as overlay. The map is an ImageViewTouch element (src: https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) and has zooming and panning capabilities through touch.

My current layout is as follows:

```
<it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clickable="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:shadowColor="#000"
        android:text="This is some random text"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The question is, how can I 'lock' the position of the TextView (and other elements) to the location according to the map. So the TextView moves and resizes as the user zooms or pans the image.

I'm new to Android UI development so I don't know what direction to take, like iterating over all elements and moving/resizing them according to the image scale and scroll values or...